# linking not done using make command

Tags: make, makefile

I am working on Ubuntu. I am running make command but it is not working, an error is generated. I am sharing the error below.

```
gcc: warning: pr1: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc pr1 pr2 -o my_app
/usr/bin/ld:pr1: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:pr1:2: syntax error
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:2: my_app] Error 1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQeJw.png)

Comment: Instead of sharing the picture, prefer copying the text in the terminal and pasting it in as text with code formatting in your question. to find the error, you will need to inspect the makefile that you attempt to process. It is not the `make`  command itself that is in error.

Comment: Please always copy & paste error messages from the terminal into a code block in your question, do not post screenshots only.

Comment: What exactly is `pr1`? it doesn't have a recognized source or object code extension, and you're not passing a `-x` option - and you appear to be providing it to both a compile command `gcc -c` and a link command